# Create new array from existing array php

Tags: php, loops, foreach

Hi guys need help with foreach loop, I need to create array, called `a` with the items: `[10, 3, 45, 98, 4, 7, 56, 23, 3, 1]`. And then use a for-each loop to sum each item with 10 and put them in a new array called `b`.

Check code below it work on the same $a array but how to put them in a new array?

```
$a = [10, 3, 45, 98, 4, 7, 56, 23, 3, 1];
$b = [];

foreach ($a as &$value) {
    $value = 10 + $value;
}
echo $a;
```

Comment: Umm... change `$value = ` to `$b[] = ` maybe???

Comment: @AbraCadaver I assume you mean `$b[] = `

Comment: This reads like a homework question of the like. We suggest that you prefer to solve such questions yourself. If you just ask here and copy the answers you receive you will not really learn much.

Comment: @SeanBright: Yes.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I'm not gonna copy it, just need help how to put in new array.

Comment: array_push(); http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to assign sum to each key in new array.

```
$a = [10, 3, 45, 98, 4, 7, 56, 23, 3, 1];
$b = [];

foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    $b[$key] = 10 + $value;
}

var_dump($b); // prints $b
```

See https://3v4l.org/bURiM.

This will also work if you will use `$a` as associative array:

```
$a = ['a' => 10, 'b' => 3, 'c' => 45];
$b = [];

foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    $b[$key] = 10 + $value;
}

var_dump($b); // prints $b
```

See https://3v4l.org/UOBok.

Answer (score 10):

Generating a new array by performing the same operation on all elements of an input array is referred to as [mapping](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/307639/what-does-mapping-mean-in-programming), and this can also be done using a higher-order function in PHP, unless you are specifically required to use a `foreach` loop for some reason.

```
$b = array_map(function($n) { return $n + 10; }, $a);
```

Or with arrow function (as of PHP 7.4)

```
$b = array_map(fn($n) => $n + 10, $a);
```